# How to create live event for css

Tags: jquery, css, events, live

How can I make this code live?

`$("#send_button").css({ opacity: 0.2 });`

This code is applied on an element from inside a div on `document ready`. That div gets replaced by other div on an event, then It gets reinserted again dinamically with `html()`.

This is the div (example):

`<div id="dinamic_div"><img src="image.jpg" id="send_button"></div>`

Comment: sorry, it's `send_button`, I wrote it wrong :)

Comment: There is no "live" for CSS applied with javascript, it's only applied on elements currently on the page. To insert CSS that will also work for future elements, you should just set the styles in your stylesheet. If that's not possible, you'll have to insert a style tag into the head or style the element when it's created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a CSS rule and it will apply to any  object that matches the selector even if it's created dynamically.

```
#send_button {opacity: 0.2;}
```

Or, make a CSS rule with the opacity on a class name and put the class name on your button:

```
.lightButton {opacity: 0.2;}

<div id="dinamic_div">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="lightButton" id="send_button">
</div>
```

---

If you have to do it with javascript, then you're easiest method would be to just style the dynamic object when it's created.

If you can't do that, you could create a CSS rule with javascript.

Working example:

```
var html = '<div id="dinamic_div"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=Hello" id="send_button"></div>';

$(html).appendTo(document.body);

var style = document.createElement("style");
style.type = "text/css";
style.innerHTML = "#send_button {opacity: 0.2;}";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Cnbvg/

Comment: I made it with CSS. Thank you!